# Find $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of a sequence and prove $\liminf a_n \leq \limsup a_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

I have a question of finding lim sup and lim inf of $a_n=\frac{1}{n} + (-1)^n$ and prove $\liminf  a_n \leq \limsup  a_n.$
So the work below is what I did for the first part.

$a_{odd\ n} = \frac{1}{n}-1$ and $a_{even\ n} = \frac{1}{n}+1.$ So $\limsup  a_n = 1$ and $\liminf  a_n = -1.$
How do I prove the second part?? I tried to use the definition but I am confused with the definition.

Comment: It must be the other way around, $a_{odd}=\frac{1}{n}-1$ and $a_{even}=\frac{1}{n}+1$

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity tahnks.. fixed!!

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353642/x-n-leq-y-n-implies-liminf-x-n-leq-liminf-y-n-and-limsup-x-n-leq-lims (and other questions shown there among linked questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose if you can see that $\liminf a_n = -1$ and $\limsup a_n = +1$, then trivially $\liminf a_n \leq \limsup a_n$.

Indeed for "any" sequence that is the case, the definition forces that, so it is among properties of limsup and liminf.

From Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior

Whenever $\liminf x_n$ and $\limsup x_n $both exist, we have
$\liminf_{n \to \infty}x_n\leq \limsup_{n \to \infty}x_n$.

Comment: I thought I have to prove it somehow..thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to prove $\liminf \{ x_n \} \leq \limsup \{ x_n \}$ for a general real sequence $\{ x_n \}$.  Set $L = \liminf \{ x_n \}$ and $S = \limsup \{ x_n \}$, and suppose for the sake of contradiction that $L > S$.  Say $L = S + h$ for some $h > 0$.  Then there are infinitely many $n$ for which $x_n \in (L - h, L + h)$.  Therefore, there are infinitely many $n$ for which $x_n > S$, contradicting the definition of $S$.  Hence, $L \leq S$.