# If $a_n \geq b_n$ and $b_n$ converges to $b$ then $\liminf a_n\geq b$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$ are sequences in $\mathbb R$. Suppose $a_n\geq b_n$ and $\{b_n\}$ converges to $b$. Can we conclude that $\liminf a_n\geq b$. What if we further assume $\{a_n\}$ is bounded below?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353642/x-n-leq-y-n-implies-liminf-x-n-leq-liminf-y-n-and-limsup-x-n-leq-lims

Comment: There seems no need to assume the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is bounded below: assume that $\{a_n\}$ is not bounded below, then there is a subsequence of $\{b_n\}$ which diverges to $-\infty$. This is a contradiction to the assumption that $\{b_n\}$ converges. If we are allowing $-\infty$ as a possible limit, then in any case we have $\liminf\{a_n\}\geq-\infty$.