# Prove that $\limsup X_n \leq \liminf Y_n$ and $\limsup X_n \leq \liminf X_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

From this post [$X_n\leq Y_n$ implies $\liminf X_n \leq \liminf Y_n$ and $\limsup X_n \leq \limsup Y_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353642/x-n-leq-y-n-implies-liminf-x-n-leq-liminf-y-n-and-limsup-x-n-leq-lims), I know that $X_n\leq Y_n$ implies $\liminf X_n \leq \liminf Y_n$ and $\limsup X_n \leq \limsup Y_n$. Is it also true that $$\limsup X_n \leq \liminf Y_n$$
And that  $$\limsup X_n \leq \liminf X_n$$

Comment: Try $$X_n=Y_n$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_n$ be an alternating sequence $\{-1,1,-1,1...\}$ and $Y_n=\{0,2,0,2...\}$. Then $\limsup X_n= 1$ and $\liminf Y_n=0$,  yet  $X_n<Y_n$ for every $n$.

Comment: Thanks!! And what about $\limsup X_n \leq \liminf X_n$?