# When does equality for $x_n < y_n \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be 2 sequences such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n$ exist. Then:

($\forall n$)   $x_n < y_n  \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n$. On what condition on $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ does the equality hold?

**Background to the question:**

I am trying to prove Cauchy Schwarz inequality in integral form for real-valued functions using the Cauchy Schwarz inequality in summation form i.e.
If $f,g \geq 0$ are square (Riemann) integrable, prove $(\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx)^2 \leq (\int_a^b f(x)^2dx)(\int_a^b g(x)^2dx) $ using $(\sum u_iv_i)^2 \leq (\sum u_i^2)(\sum v_i^2) $.

Proof: If $P(x,t)$ be a tagged partition of $[a,b]$.
\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx &:= \lim_{||P|| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)g(x_i) \Delta x_i \\
&= \lim_{||P|| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i)\sqrt{\Delta x_i})(g(x_i)\sqrt{\Delta x_i}) \\
&\leq \lim_{||P|| \rightarrow 0} \sqrt{(\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)^2\Delta x_i) (\sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)^2\Delta x_i)} \\(\text{Using C-S inequality and the limit inequality I asked above.}) \\
&= \sqrt{\lim_{||P|| \rightarrow 0} (\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)^2\Delta x_i) (\sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)^2\Delta x_i)} \\
\Rightarrow (\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx)^2 &\leq \lim_{||P|| \rightarrow 0} (\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)^2\Delta x_i) \lim_{||P|| \rightarrow 0}(\sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)^2\Delta x_i) \\
&= (\int_a^b f(x)^2dx)(\int_a^b g(x)^2dx)
\end{align}
I want to check for what $f,g$ does the equality hold. For this I need to know when the equality to $x_n \leq y_n \Rightarrow \lim x_n \leq \lim y_n$ holds! Hence the question.

Comment: There is no way to describe it in general.

Comment: The existence of limit is equivalent to limsup = liminf, so it's answered in the [first question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/353642/290189) in the list of related questions.

Comment: @ GNU Supporter: I know how to prove the inequality, but I was looking for some insight on when the equality holds.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n =L$$

and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n =M$$

We show that $ L\le M$

Suppose on the contrary, we have $l > M$.

Let $\epsilon = \frac {l-M}{2}$

For a large enough n = we have both $x_n>L-\epsilon=\frac {L+M}{2}$ and  $y_n < M+\epsilon = \frac {L+M}{2}$$

That makes $ x_n > y_n$ which is not possible due to our assumption. contradiction.

The equality hold if $|x_n-y_n |\to 0$

Comment: For the equality condition, haven't you just restated it as it is/

Comment: True, but there is not much to say about it. We can give examples but that is about it.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (y_n-x_n) = 0$, then the limits must be equal.

Comment: Isn't that just restating the equality?