# To prove $a \leq b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

. Given $\lim_{a_n} = a, \lim{b_n} = b$  Given two sequences such that $a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a \leq b$

Assume : $a > b$
Take $$\epsilon = \frac{a-b}{4}$$. so there exists $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that
so then $$a_n \in (\frac{3a+4}{4}, a+\epsilon), b_n \in (b_n-\epsilon, \frac{a+3b}{4})$$

Take $N = \operatorname{max} (N_1, N_2)$ so that we have $a_N \geq b_N$. but this is contradiction.

I am not sure if this is correct way to do this. only idea i have is to take disjoint intervels

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does equality for $x_n &lt; y_n \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n$ hold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773589/when-does-equality-for-x-n-y-n-rightarrow-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-x-n-l)

Comment: What's your question? I can't read this.

Comment: A useful property is that $c_n$ converges to $c$ iff $\{n: c_n\not\in U\}$ is finite whenever $U$ is a neighborhood of $c$.... If $a-b=r>0$ then $\{n: a_n\not\in (a-r/2,a+r/2)\}$ and $\{n: b_n\not\in (b-r/2,b+r/2)\}$ are finite sets, but there are infinitely many $n$, so there would exist $n$ with  $b-r/2<b_n<b+r/2=a-r/2<a_n<a+r/2.$

Comment: Other than the typo  in your posting of "Assume $~a > n$", $~$ which I corrected, your posting is fine.  I have no explanation for the torrent of responses that your posting received, nor the downvote that your posting has received.  I repeat, your analysis is valid, **as is**.

Comment: Also, for clarity, I would have (instead) written that $$a_n \in (a - \epsilon, a+ \epsilon), ~b_n \in (b - \epsilon, b+\epsilon).$$  Since your definition of $~\epsilon~$ implies that $~(b+\epsilon) < (a - \epsilon),~$ you would then have your desired contradiction.

Comment: @user2661923 ok thanks

Comment: @user2661923 post answer and i will accept and upvote

Comment: answer posted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response given per the specific request of the OP (i.e. original poster).

Assume $~a > b,~$ and then derive a contradiction.

Let $~\epsilon~$ denote $~\dfrac{a-b}{4} \implies \epsilon > 0.$

Then, per the constraints of the problem:

- $\exists ~N_1 \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that 
  for all $~n \geq N_1, ~a_n \in (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon).$
- $\exists ~N_2 \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that 
  for all $~n \geq N_2, ~b_n \in (b - \epsilon, b + \epsilon).$

Set $~n = \max(N_1,N_2).$

This implies that :

- $b_n < b + \epsilon.$
- $a - \epsilon < a_n.$
- Also, per the definition of $~\epsilon,~$
  $(b + \epsilon) < (a - \epsilon).$

So, you can conclude that

$$b_n < (b + \epsilon) < (a - \epsilon) < a_n.$$

This contradicts the constraint that for all $~n, ~a_n \leq b_n.$

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that $a < b + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Fix $\epsilon$, and choose $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that
$$
n > N_1 \implies |a_n - a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}, \; n > N_2 \implies |b_n - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
Let $N := \max(N_1, N_2)$. For any $n > N$, we have $|a_n - a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|b_n - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. In particular,
$$
a - \frac{\epsilon}{2} < a_n \leq b_n < b + \frac{\epsilon}{2},
$$
i.e., $a - \frac{\epsilon}{2} < b + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, hence $a < b + \epsilon$, as claimed.

Comment: what about my proof