# Explanation requested for contradiction in lim inf proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I am working through the way Brian Scott did it in this comment and am wondering why the $-\infty$ case causes a contradiction.
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/353697/626797

Question

> Let $X_n\leq Y_n$ for each $n\in \Bbb N$. Show that $\liminf X_n \leq \liminf Y_n$ and $\limsup X_n \leq \limsup Y_n$.

Brian Scott response:

> Suppose that $X_n\le Y_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and suppose, to get a contradiction, that $\liminf_nY_n<\liminf_nX_n$. Then there is a subsequence $\langle Y_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ that converges to some $y<\liminf_nX_n$. Show that either $\langle X_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\to-\infty$, or $\langle X_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has a subsequence that converges to some $x\le y$; both are impossible, since $y<\liminf_nX_n$.

I do not see the contradiction during the case when $x\to -\infty$. This implies $y<-\infty$, right? I don't think this is a contradiction and if it isn't, then where is the contradiction during this case?

Comment: In my opinion, this is very badly explained. I would go as follows: Assume $Y := \liminf Y_n < \liminf X_n =: X$. Then there exists $Y < Z < X$. There is a subsequence $(Y_{n_k})$ of $(Y_n)$ converging to $Y$ and $Y_{n_k} < Z$ for all $k$. Now, consider $(X_{n_k})$. As $X = \liminf X_n$, there are only finitely many $X_n < Z$. Hence $X_{n_k}\ge Z$ for almost every $k$. And for these $k$ we have $Y_{n_k} < z\le X_{n_k}$. Contradiction!

Comment: @amsmath That is much easier to understand. One question: how do you know that for all $k$, $Y_{n_k} <Z$?

Comment: I choose $(Y_{n_k})$ such that this holds. I can do that because I can choose a small neighborhood of $Y$ that does not contain $Z$. And in this neighborhood there will be infinitely many $Y_n$ as $Y$ is a limit point of $(Y_n)$. So $Y_n<Z$ for these $Y_n$. From these infinitely many $Y_n$'s I choose a subsequence.